# tx_news-Viewhelper: Plaintext output

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I need the teaser as pure plain text , without any links or text formatting in the Latest view, the possibility . Is it provided for a corresponding ViewHelper or a different approach ?

HTML entities , it should not be served as `&amp;` for `&` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The news list is rendered using a partial for each item (`Resources/Private/Partials/List/Item.html`). In that, you can see the line used for rendering the teaser:

```
{newsItem.teaser -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: '{settings.cropMaxCharacters}', respectWordBoundaries:'1') -> f:format.html()}
```

If you remove the last view helper `f:format.html()`, then it won’t be converted to HTML. If you replace it with `f:format.raw()` (in case you have HTML in the teaser), then the HTML will be output as is, w/o converting < to &lt; and > to &gt; etc.

When overriding the partials, you should not directly modify the extension, but do it in an upgrade-safe way. For that, put them in your site extension or into `fileadmin/` and add that partials path to the TS config:

```
plugin.tx_productview {
    view {
        partialRootPaths.1 = [path to partials folder]
    }
}
```

For `news`, there is also a special mechanism: you can set a constant

```
plugin.tx_news.view.partialRootPath = […]
```

to the path.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<f:format.stripTags>` Viewhelper.
To ensure all html entities are decoded use `<f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>`
So you can use:

```
<f:format.stripTags>
  <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
    {newsTeaserVar}
  </f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
</f:format.stripTags>
```

Comment: Internally, this results in `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(htmlentitydecode(htmlspecialchars($newsTeaserVar))));` equivalent processing, due to how escaping works in Fluid. Normally, the `htmlentitiesDecode` step will not be required and can be replaced with `f:format.raw` if the HTML is trusted: `{newsTeaserVar -> f:format.raw() -> f:format.stripTags()}`.